# how i can learn ruby and rails?And implemented to them

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how we can implement ruby and rails?

Please help me to implement the ruby and rails.

Hello Class

```
class Hello
   def initialize( name )
      @name = name.capitalize
   end

   def salute
      puts "Hello #{@name}!"
   end
end
```

Comment: Google some tutorial on RoR, before your question gets downvoted.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a very clear question, so it's not really possible to answer it. For general guides on how to build a Rails app, this is not the right site. Look for a tutorial that you can work through. There are lots online. Come here and ask a specific question when/if you get stuck and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this url
http://railstutorial.org/book

That is a great ROR tutorial.
you can learn the common knowledge about web as well as ruby on rails.
Best Regards
Jin

Answer (score 0):

http://railscasts.com/

This is probably your best tutorials on the web you can find for ruby on rails. But I would still suggest your read some fundamental books, if you can, taking a ruby on rails bootcamp is the best way to learn. For example, in Vancouver, Canada. We have a very good ruby on rails bootcamp from http://www.codecore.com/